# I'm not able to get my React web app working without npm start..Any assistance

Tags: npm

I'm not able to get my create-react-app working without npm start. Can anyone assist in what to do.

Comment: We're going to need more information. What are you trying to do, and what behavior are you expecting but not seeing? Are there errors?

Comment: Im trying to upload my create-react-app web app to my host. npm start works but after I host it it doesn't. I also viewed the index.html file from my folder and had the same problem as when it was hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `npm run build`? You can’t deploy the project itself. You have to let webpack build a deployable artifact. See the [CRA readme](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md).

`npm start` is running a development server so you don’t have to keep building it to see every change, but that’s just for dev convenience.